# Can we reduce a 3rd order linear ODE to a 2nd order linear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This ODE came out in my exam

$$y''' -4y'' -12y'=x^2 $$

However, I was only taught till 2nd order linear ODEs. Can we reduce this to a 2nd order or even a 1st order ODE and then use substitution to find the general solutions at the end? How does it work?

Comment: Yes substitute $w=y'$ or you can integrate the DE and reduce the order.

Answer (score 5):

We are given

$$y''' -4y'' -12y'=x^2$$

We can set

$$\begin{align} y_1' &= y' = y_2 \\ y_2' &= y'' = y_3 \\ y_3' &= y''' = 4 y'' + 12y' + x^2 = 12 y_2 + 4 y_3 + x^2 \end{align}$$

In matrix form, we have a system $Y'(x) = AY(x) + g(x)$ as

$$Y' = \begin{bmatrix} y_1' \\ y_2' \\ y_3' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 12 & 4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ x^2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now you have a nonhomogeneous system and solve that using the standard methods or numerical methods.

Also, there are other methods to solve the original ODE, like Undetermined Coefficients, Laplace Transforms, Substitution/Integration and others.

You get the solution

$$y(x) = -\frac{1}{2} c_1 e^{-2 x}+\frac{1}{6} c_2 e^{6 x}+c_3-\frac{x^3}{36}+\frac{x^2}{36}-\frac{7 x}{216}$$

Comment: is your matrix thing really better or something than the good ol' calculus 1 way of thinking $w=y'$ ?

Comment: What does that matter? This is the answer to what is being asked. Period. I also provided hints for other approaches.

Comment: Moo, just wondering. If it's better, then why not do it right?

Answer (score 0):

**Part1**. Yes *because* there's no original $y$ there. You can set $w=y'$ to get

$$w'' -4w' -12w=x^2 $$

**Part2**. You can't do this kind of substitution if there's an original $y$ eg

$$y''' -4y'' -12y'+7y=x^2 $$

because then you'd get something like

$$w'' -4w' -12w+7W=x^2 $$

where $W$ is some (any? Idk) antiderivative of $w$.

**Part3**. Anyway so go right ahead and apply what you know Gasai to

$$w'' -4w' -12w=x^2 $$

If I remember correctly, then this is

1. Solve this $w'' -4w' -12w=0 $
2. by solving this $d^2-4d-12=0$
3. Solving $w'' -4w' -12w=x^2 $ given solution of $w'' -4w' -12w=0 $ or something. You know Gasai what to do.